# error, not run program (windows)

Tags: windows, exe, direct3d

I createa a program on windows, but if you install new windows, my program doesn't run.

error : **failed to initialize direct3D.
make surre you have at least DirectX 9.0c installed,have driver for your graphics card and have not disabled 3D acceleration in display settings.
initializeEngineGraphics failed**

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12XhZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because the Os is changed, try to look for on the net a reason why it gives you that error, e.g. copy and paste the error on google